# Programmer for 68HC711 PLCC 52-pin

Tags: microcontroller, programmer

I'm trying to find a way to make a backup copy of a HC68711 52-pin PLCC (eventually to another device) that is in a piece of equipment I own.

I see various and sundry adapters and the like, but since this is an older device I worry that I need more bits than what I've seen available.

Can anyone recommend a set of tools (h/w and s/w) necessary to do this?

I'm not looking for a specific model, per se, just the type of thing(s) necessary.  There's a few "programmers" out there - many are inexpensive far-east-specials - but the set of options seems daunting.  BTW, it's an internal ROM device and I am concerned that it may be set up to prevent copying (if that's a mode the 68HC711 series has)

Comment: Do you mean 68HC711 microcontroller? From which manufacturer, and which exact submodel? What do you intend to back up from them? The code may be in external ROM and if it isn't the internal ROM may have some kind of protection that it is not readable by standard means to protect from copying and cloning. Also, recommending what to buy is off-topic.

Comment: The 68HC(7)11 has a bootstrap mode where it boots up to execute a small piece of built-in bootloader code. That code (located at $BF00 when bootstrap mode is enabled) can read a small program into the internal RAM from the serial port and run that program. You could write a piece of code to read the ROM areas you're interested in and output them on the serial port. Details are described in the datasheet. I used it all the time when I worked with the 68HC11.

Comment: To use bootstrap mode you need to be able to set the MODA and MODB inputs at boot and have access to the serial port.

Answer (score 1):

You can find old EVBs on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/273787506245). You can research which one works.

Now, getting the software, and host to run it on, from 30+ years ago, may be another matter.

And it's probably locked if the particular chip you have has that feature and it was a commercial product. They were mostly (all?) OTP chips, not flash and not erasable unless they have an expensive windowed package.